# while loop didnt work

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

Hi guys, I'm trying to do the while loop.

The while loop will loop through all the orders.
It works but somehow it doesn't while loop through the order status.
For example, order 4 status is pending, but order 5 status shows nothing.
I suspect I placed the brackets wrongly.

This is my code.

```
<form action="results-action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>

<table width="600" border="1">
<tr><td><h2>Pending Order</h2></td></tr>
<tr>

<th scope="col">Order ID</th>
<th scope="col">Name</th>
<th scope="col">Address</th>
<th scope="col">Product Name</th>
<th scope="col">Produt Quantity</th>
<th scope="col">Price</th>
<th scope="col">Order status</th>
</tr>

<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" value='<?=$row['virtuemart_order_id']?>' name="orderid" id="virtuemart_order_id"></td>
<td><?=$row['first_name']?></td>
<td><?=$row['address_1']?></td>
<td><?=$row['order_item_name']?></td>
<td><?=$row['product_quantity']?></td>
<td><?=$row['product_final_price'] ?></td>
<td><select name="change">
    <?php 
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?=$row2['order_status_code'] ?>"><?=$row2['order_status_name'] ?></option>
    <?php
    } //end inner while
    ?>
</td>
</tr>

<?php
} //end outer while
?>

</table>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Update status" name="update status"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: What are `$result` and `$result2`? I don't see how the inner `while` could run more than once if you're not somehow resetting `$result2`.

Comment: you didn't end the `<select>` by the way

Comment: This won't solve your current problem, but look into [separation of presentation and content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content) and [alternative syntax for control structures](http://us.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Comment: also an adivce. use `join` because as i see it, this can be done by one query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the same rows every time in the inner `while` you will have to reset the internal pointer of the mysqli result set. For this, you can use the [`mysqli_data_seek()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php)

You will end up with something like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    // snip ...
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        // snip
    }
    mysqli_data_seek($result2, 0);
    // snip
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please also ensure the `<select>` has unique name, otherwise all your status will be captured wrongly.

```
<select name="change_<?=$row['row_id']?>">
```

Something like that.